# Get client information for IIS 6

Tags: vba, iis, vbscript, active-directory, iis-6

Is it possible to get IP address of client connected to IIS server and send warning message to all user connected to IIS

I try this:

`Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")
For Each objItem in colItems
        dtmWMIDate = objItem.AccountExpires
        strReturn = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmWMIDate)
        Wscript.Echo "Account Expires: " & strReturn
        Wscript.Echo "Full Name: " & objItem.FullName
        Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name 
Next`

this give me information about my computer not all user connected to IIS

Answer (score 0):

The users address is in `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`.

For all users you would store them in application scope using the session start/end events similar to [this approach](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-current-users/sessions.html). (Use a delimited string or array or a known thread-safe collection, do not use a Dictionary)